# 'Repa' performance for planetary simulation

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

I have written a simulation of the outer planets of the solar system using the [Euler symplectic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) and implemented this a) using `repa` and b) using `yarr`.

[`yarr` seems to perform about x30 quicker than `repa`](http://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/planetary-simulation-with-excursions-in-symplectic-manifolds-6/).

Given this, I didn't even try to use parallelism. Is there any obvious performance problems in my `repa` code? The repository is at [github](https://github.com/idontgetoutmuch/Leapfrog). I can produce a cut-down `repa`-only version if this is helpful, but then you won't get the performance comparison against `yarr`.

Alternatively, how do I debug performance issues in `repa`?

Comment: Could you also publish the `Initial` module, so this compiles?

Comment: https://github.com/idontgetoutmuch/Leapfrog/blob/master/Initial.hs

Answer (score 2):

Most Euler numeric integration methods suffer from cumulative round-off error that will eventually cause the simulation to "blow up".  You may want to investigate advanced numerical integration methods, such as 4th-order Runge-Kutta or predictor-corrector.

Another place where n-body problem simulations become sticky is when two bodies get very close, such as a moon with a very eccentric orbit about its planet.  If one uses fixed time increments for the simulation, the error during large changes of angular velocity can lead to division-by-zero errors or division by very small values that result in the simulation blowing up.  Use of a variable delta-t that depends on the angular velocity can be beneficial.

These suggestions are based on running many such simulations as a project for an undergraduate physics course I took in 1973, while testing various numerical integration methods.  Runge-Kutta and predictor corrector methods have been around since the dawn of digital computing and a number of books are available.  See, *e.g.*, ***Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing*** by William H. Press, Brian P. Flannery, Saul A. Teukolsky and William T. Vetterling. (Cambridge University Press, 1989)

Comment: Note that NR codes are actually copyrighted, so you can't *really* use them in public codes.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to address my question which is about the *performance* of the *repa* library for this particular problem. As an aside RK4 suffers from the same problem as the explicit and implicit Euler methods which is that energy is not conserved; I could have added "softening" to address the problem of planets getting too close but for the roughly circular orbits considered in the article this is unnecessary.

Comment: Kyle, I am not implying that the code in Numerical Recipes be used without permission.  Many examples shown in the book are based on non-copyrighted numerical computation methods, some even predating development of digital computers.  It's a good place to start if one is unfamiliar with the various techniques.